# Can I still be sold plumbing fixtures that contain lead?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, lead

I'm shopping for brass or stainless ball valve to replace shutoff on a plumbing line. I see on ebay that some valves are advertised as "lead-free" while others are not.  I would've assumed ALL brass/SS valves are lead-free.  If I'm concerned with lead, do I need to screen specifically for lead?

Comment: Some types of brass contain a significant percent lead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass : "To enhance the machinability of brass, lead is often added in concentrations of around 2% [which] can lead to significant lead leaching from brasses of comparatively low lead content."

Comment: Can you be sold them in what jurisdiction?

Comment: On eBay - sure. From a reputable vendor as water plumbing - less likely, but as plumbing for heating, yes.

Comment: Seems relevant: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/free.png

Comment: The type of plumbing is very relevant here. Laws for potable water supplies are very much more strict than general plumbing (waste, heating, garden, etc).

Comment: Proper link so you can read the hover text: https://xkcd.com/641/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you go to your local hardware store, no. Products sold in the US [have to be lead free, since 1996](https://www.epa.gov/dwstandardsregulations/use-lead-free-pipes-fittings-fixtures-solder-and-flux-drinking-water)

> In 1996 Congress further amended the Safe Drinking Water Act, requiring plumbing fittings and fixtures (endpoint devices) to be in compliance with voluntary lead leaching standards. The amendments also prohibited the introduction into commerce of any pipe, pipe or plumbing fitting or fixture that is not lead free.

Ebay is a bit of the "wild west", because you often have products sold direct to consumers from foreign countries (i.e. they bypass US regulations because they're sold and shipped from that country to you directly). It's easy to find Chinese or Indian products on there, and neither country has that prohibition against lead. So, yes, you probably need to screen on Ebay. If it's a serious concern for you, just buy from a US company or your local hardware store.

Comment: +1 for buy from a US company or your local hardware store. Even though I'm not from the US. It's worth realizing there are no obvious bonuses when buying locally, including laws governing manufacture and sale.

Comment: @DRF You mean non-obvious?

Comment: Buying from a US company is not adequate. The major US industrial supply company I get parts from lists a wide variety of leaded brass pipes and fittings, intended for industrial applications. They note which ones are approved for potable water.

Comment: @immibis Yeap. My bad.

Comment: The problem with this answer is the law it's based on only applies to the "wetted surfaces" of pipes, fittings and joining compounds that provide "water for human consumption". ***Plumbing* is more than potable water.** Given the useful properties of lead, it seems *entirely* plausible that pipes and fittings not intended for water for human consumption can still be bought with lead in them. [Netduke's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/126609/24343) doesn't quote the law for potable water supplies but is a more accurate answer to *this* question as it stands.

Comment: The confusing part here is at home depot, some kitchen faucets are marked  as "lead free" and some *aren't* and here's one that's even marked "low lead" As far as I'm aware you can even buy "leaded" faucets at home depot, ex: https://www.homedepot.com/p/LDR-Industries-Exquisite-4-in-Centerset-2-Handle-Low-Lead-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Brushed-Nickel-15717507/205405373 "low lead" so my hunch is that some of the ones "not marked lead free" are leaded to some extent.  Perhaps they're just less than the "0.25% lead" requirement to be considered "lead free" or what not?

Comment: If far more sophisticated industrial products, like solid state relays(!), have been found as counterfeits on ebay... plumbing fixtures might make pretty low hanging fruit....

Comment: "The amendments also prohibited the introduction into commerce of any pipe, pipe or plumbing fitting or fixture that is not lead free." - lead free by the 1996 definition is <8% lead. The 2011 redefinition to 0.25% (not directly comparable, measurement method differs!) seems to only apply to potable water components, not all plumbing bits. Industrial/irrigation parts misrepresented/mislabelled could be a risk. Also, 2011 is not that far ago, old stock might be labelled lead free but pertain to the 1996 definition.

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of plumbing fittings used for non-potable water that are still being made which contain lead in the brass alloy. The lead free ball valves usually have a NSF icon on them.

Ball valves are used in many applications and industries and only the ones used specifically for drinking water would need to be lead free.

For example:

Leaded http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=3391

Non-Leaded http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=6836

Its hard to tell if it is lead free or not just by the look, you may have to look up its part number online to find out.

Comment: What tells you on the Watts website that the valve you linked is leaded?

Comment: Only their lead free model is NSF certified to be safe for drinking water, and the lead free part number begins with LF. The physical valve also has the letters "LF" on the body.